# How to Create a Fluid Multiple Column Layout?

Tags: css, css-float

I would like to create a simple fluid layout whereby 4 columns of Equal width, drops to 3 columns of Equal width once the viewport is below a specific width, and then to 2 columns of Equal width at a further specified viewport width. When a column falls away, it should drop to the next line, thus display below the original columns.

Any pointers or a simple fiddle with colored divs on how to achieve this would be most helpful!

Thanks Devin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the useful pointers given. Here's is an easy fiddle illustrating how it can be acheived: jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/QFhh9

Answer (score 1):

You can set the column (div) widths with your CSS, but you're going to need javascript to do the part where it switches to 3 or 2 columns when the window is a certain width. CSS alone doesn't have that kind of logic built in.

Comment: CSS *can* do it: [media queries](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries).

Comment: They work in IE9: http://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries. You do indeed need JavaScript such as [Respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) for lower versions of IE.

Answer (score 1):

A general example: http://dabblet.com/gist/2996934

Comment: Thanks, thats useful. Here's is an even easier to use fiddle illustrating how it can be acheived: http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/QFhh9/

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [holy bible sample](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/ultimate-3-column-holy-grail-pixels.htm)

If youre willing and able, see how new standards will make progress in css column-count:
http://1plusdesign.com/articles/the-future-of-newspaper-column-style-layout-with-css-3/